# Using Donut chart in oracle apex. I have created links on the partitions of the donut chart, when clicked will open a modal window to another page

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

Using Donut chart in oracle apex. I have created links on the partitions of the donut chart, when clicked will open a modal window to another page.but when i close the dialog I cannot re-open the dialog for the partition I clicked on before.It remains highlighted but does not re-open the dialog.
Is this a known issue in Oracle apex donut charts?
let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Query used

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       dl.description,
      e.id
FROM dept_location dl,
     departments   d,
     employees     e
WHERE dl.id = d.location_id
 AND d.id  = e.dept_id
  GROUP BY dl.description, e.id;
```

1. On the Graph -> Attributes -> type: donut
2. Click on report -> Link -> Type -> Redirect to page in this application
3. Enter page number and pass 'ID' or whatever information needed to page
4. Set Items -> Name: P16_ID -> Value: &ID.   'with ID being used from query above'
5. Clear Session State ->  Clear Cache -> page linking to
6. Set the page you are opening up to be a Modal Page -> Page Mode -> Modal Dialog

This worked fine for me when closing the page and being able to click on the same value again

Comment: What version of apex did you use?. I am working on 5.1
I do not see these attributes.

Comment: Hi Raj, JET charts were new in 5.1 so I wouldn't be surprised if there were some bugs. At this point, that release is over 2 years old. I recommend trying to reproduce in a 19.2 instance and, if you can't reproduce the issue, try to do an upgrade. You'll get lots of other goodies too! :)